# How to insert timeuuid record in cassandra version 2.1.7 using java

Tags: cassandra

how to insert  timeuuid record  in cassandra using java

Answer (score 3):

import com.datastax.driver.core.utils.UUIDs;

Insert stmt = QueryBuilder.insertInto("keyspaceName", "tableName")
                    .value("timeUuidField", UUIDs.timeBased());

ResultSet rs = session.execute(stmt);